# how to access dynamically created radiobuttons in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 foreach (var qList in Model)    { 

@Html.RadioButton("InputAnswer[" + index + "]", "Yes", false, 
          new { onclick = "LoadQuestion('" + qList.ID + "','Yes')" })<label>Yes</label>

@Html.RadioButton("InputAnswer[" + index + "]", "No", false,
                  new { onclick = "LoadQuestion('" + qList.ID + "','No')" })<label>No</label>                                

}
```

Based on the model it will create 1 , 2 , 3 or 4 set's of radio buttons as ( Yes & No). I need to get the input from the radio button's ( Yes or No ) and i need to display child controls dynamically.

Need Help: Please provide me some help. It would be great if you could suggest me how to take up this task from controller -> model -> view.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just pass

```
LoadQuestion(this)
```

in the LoadQuestion javascript call. That will give you a reference to the current radiobutton that was clicked. Then you can use that reference to interrogate the radiobutton for information (id, value, checked, etc...) That should then allow you to toggle other values based on the state of the radiobutton.

Comment: Thanks spinon. I'm able to generate the child controls based on the radio button's i/p. Actual problem is i'm able to select only one set of radio button's. if i select the first group (Yes/ No) the second group (Yes / No) will loss it's state. This issue is because each time i select the option (Yes/No) i use JQuery Ajax() to call the action method in turn and the resultant will be binded to a DIV in the jquery success call back function. Hope I'm clear. if my approach is wrong please suggest me some new approach with some code samples. Thanks in advance.